# What are those squiggle lines called when a character’s stomach growls?

Tags: tropes, pretty-cure

[image]

What are those squiggle lines called when a character’s stomach growls?

Comment: Well, they're what you just said: squiggle lines that serve as a visual indicator for the source of a growl.

Comment: What are the squiggle lines called when a character’s stomach growls?

Comment: They just indicate a sound or source of a sound and don’t have a special name.

Comment: I thought the same was used in Western cartoons [e.g.](https://www.pixtastock.com/illustration/47679563). Does that have a name in English?